# Security of getting access key from auth server

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have a question about the security of getting access key in auth server:

When the authorization server redirect to the client server with the authorization code in the query param of the url and then after the redirection the client will make a post to the authorization server with a secret key to get the access key. What if someone get the url with query param sent by auth server and copy pasted it to the browser, will the auth server give the access key?

I mean they have same route and it means it will go through the post api and use the secret key of that client to get the access key. How to prevent this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of basic protections here that are sufficient for most use cases:

- The connection between the client server and authorization server should use SSL so that the traffic cannot be intercepted
- The infrastructure should be locked down so that attempts to intercept server to server traffic are not allowed

**FINANCIAL GRADE**

It is also possible to use stronger secrets between the client server and authorization server, such as an X509 client certificate. This ensures that if someone manages to intercept an HTTPS request they still cannot use the secret, because they do not have the private key.

OAuth is a framework so there are different ways in which it can be used. In some industry sectors, such as banking, it is required to implement higher strength profiles such as those specified in [Financial-grade Client Requirements](https://openid.net/specs/fapi-2_0-baseline-01.html#name-requirements-for-clients), which require this type of stronger secret.

**PEOPLE RISKS**

A rogue employee could potentially steal either type of secret. Bear in mind also though that the Authorization Code Flow requires valid user credentials in addition to the client secret.